# Is there a nicer syntax for creating two list from one parent list?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a nicer syntax for creating two list from one parent list?

```
        ids = [item["id"] for item in list1]
        addresses = [item["address"] for item in list1]
```

Something like:

```
   ids, addresses = [item["id"],item["address"]  for item in list1]
```

Comment: What makes you think this isn't idiomatic? The only problem is you named your list `list`, shadowing the built-in class of that name.

Comment: Corrected my question

Comment: You can do `ids, addresses = zip(*[item['id'], item['address'] for item in list1])`, but that produces tuples instead of lists. If you want lists specifically then `[*ids], [*addresses] = zip(*...)` works. But honestly both of these are worse than your original code.

Comment: @kaya3: You'd need some parens inside the listcomp to make that work (it treats trying to make a `tuple` without the parens as a `SyntaxError` in that context). That said, I was pretty surprised to discover `[*ids], [*addresses] = zip(*...)` actually *works*. That's pretty cool!

Comment: @ShadowRanger Right you are about the brackets, I blindly copied from the question without checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted:

```
ids, addresses = zip(*[(item["id"], item["address"]) for item in list1])
```

works. It makes a list of pairs, then uses `zip` to transpose from a `list` of two-`tuple`s to two `tuple`s, one for each key being extracted.

You could conceivably [use `operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to simplify/optimize a bit (especially if you're pulling out >2 things), which will probably run a titch faster for large inputs (`map` with a built-in implemented in C can gain some speed) e.g. (with `from operator import itemgetter` at the top of your file):

```
ids, addresses = zip(*map(itemgetter("id", "address"), list1))
```

And if the result must be `list`s, you can either use `map` to convert the `zip` outputs to `list`:

```
ids, addresses = map(list, zip(*map(itemgetter("id", "address"), list1)))
```

or use star-assignment to collect them as `list`s:

```
[*ids], [*addresses] = zip(*map(itemgetter("id", "address"), list1))
```

(credit to [kaya for pointing out the latter possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169819/is-there-a-nicer-syntax-for-creating-two-list-from-one-parent-list#comment122253740_69169819)).

That said, while these solutions might be slightly faster than two one-liners, they're *much* uglier, and code maintainers will have devote far more effort to verifying correctness vs. the trivial pair of listcomps you've already got. **Unless you've profiled and *proved* the pair of listcomps are a major performance problem, don't go experimenting with less intuitive code.**

**Update:** I decided to do some simple local tests. Turns out, on my install of CPython 3.9.5, running on Alpine through WSLv2 on Windows, the two-liner of separate simple listcomps is faster, at least for the trivial test cases I came up with for inputs. And not by a little either; the separate listcomps took less than half the time of any other solution (whether or not the results were converted back to `list`). So aside from the dubious benefit of condensing code to one line, and handling arbitrary input iterables (including iterators that can't be iterated more than once), one-lining this is strictly worse in every conceivable way than the solution you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have a one-liner, write a nested list comprehension to iterate over keys and items.

```
ids, addresses = [[d[k] for d in list1] for k in ("id", "address")]
```

With

```
list1 = [{"id": i, "address": f"s{i}"} for i in range(10)]
```

this gives

```
ids = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
addresses =  ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9']
```

Your original code is more readable IMO

Comment: IMO this seems more unclear than the code in the question.

Comment: @SuperStormer I agree.